# UIDatePicker issue with time

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, timezone, uidatepicker

I am using a UIDatePicker that I create in IB.
As I find in google the UIDatePicker locale should use the timezone and language settings of the system that the app is running on. My app is shows -3 hours although my system is set +2 hours.
Note: I am using iPad simulator

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change the timezone settings on your iPad simulator.

Settings>general>date and time>timezone

Comment: I try that but didnt work. But I want this to work on any iPad anywhere. For example if I set the timezone for Athens and someone in US using the app then the app is wont work right.